# Error connecting to google cloud and query the parquet file in apache drill

Tags: google-cloud-storage, parquet, apache-drill

I have a parquet file in google cloud bucket which I want to make a query upon.

As per one of the answer mentioned I have added the configuration in `core-site.xml` under `$DRILL_HOME/conf` as below-

```
<configuration>
        <property>
                <name>fs.gs.impl</name>
                <value>com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>fs.gs.project.id</name>
                <value><my_project_id></value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.enable</name>
                <value>true</value>
        </property>

        <property>
                <name>google.cloud.auth.service.account.json.keyfile</name>
                <value><path_to_json></value>
        </property>
</configuration>
```

Then I added this in `storage-plugins-override.conf` -

```
{
  "name": "gcs",
  "config": {
    "connection": "gs://<my_bucket>",
    "enabled": true,
    "formats": {
      "json": {
        "type": "json"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After saving this, I restarted the drill. When I am running command `show schemas;`, the `gcs` schema is not showing up which is bloking me to make any query on the parquet file in GCS.

When I run `use gcs;`

Error is coming as

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
```

Then I checked the logs in `sqlline.log`

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem not found
```

What am I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Tried in web UI of drill by creating storage plugin for gcs.
The configuration looks like:

```
{
  "type": "file",
  "connection": "gs://my-bucket",
  "config": {
    "store.format": "parquet"
  },
  "formats": {
    "parquet": {
      "type": "parquet"
    }
  },
  "enabled": true
}
```

That is also not working.

Answer (score 1):

You should install Google's [Cloud Storage connector for Hadoop](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/connectors/cloud-storage#non-clusters) into the jars/3rdparty directory on each of your Drillbits.